# how to pass authtoken via header using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass my api authtoken via the header. I am new to angular js so i am not able to do that. My code:

```
$scope.init=function(authtoken,cityname){   
        $scope.authtoken=authtoken;                     
        $scope.cityname=cityname;               
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/asas?city='+$scope.cityname+'&auth='+$scope.authtoken}).success(function(data) {
```

Right now I am passing the authtoken in the api url. But I want to pass the token via the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

usually you pass auth token in headers. Here is how i did it for one of my apps

```
angular.module('app', []).run(function($http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token;
    });
```

this will add auth token to headers by default so that you wont have to include is every time you make a request. If you want to include it in every call then it will be something like this

```
$http({
    method: 'GET', 
    url: '/api/v1/asas?city='+$scope.cityname,
    headers:{
        'Authorization': $scope.authtoken
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    //success response.
}).error(function(error){
    //failed response.
});
```

Comment: in run how i pass my authtoken .Now i get my authtoken in init function.I try to call authtoken in run but it not work like run(function($http,authtoken)

Comment: i dont think you can pass authtoken to run function.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure on application run

```
youapp.run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
});
```

or pass it throw each request

```
$http({
    url:'url',
    headers:{
        Authorization : 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
    }
})
```

[Angular $Http reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)